# Kubernetes configmap in json format error

Tags: json, kubernetes

I am trying to mount a file probes.json to an image. I started with trying to create a configmap similar to my probes.json file by manually specifying the values.

However, when I apply the replicator controller, I am getting an error.

How should I pass my JSON file to my configmap / how can I specify my values in data parameter?

I tried the below steps, however, I got an error.

```
$ cat probes.json 
[
  {
    "id": "F",
    "url": "http://frontend.stars:80/status"
  },
  {
    "id": "B",
    "url": "http://backend.stars:6379/status"
  },
  {
    "id": "C",
    "url": "http://client.stars:9000/status"
  }
]
```

Configmap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-vol-config
  namespace: stars
data:
  id: F
  id: B
  id: C
  F: |
   url: http://frontend.stars:80/status
  B: |
   url: http://backend.stars:6379/status
  C: |
   url: http://client.stars:9000/status
```

ReplicaContainer:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: management-ui
  namespace: stars
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: management-ui
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: management-ui
        image: calico/star-collect:v0.1.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9001
        volumeMounts:
          name: config-volume
        - mountPath: /star/probes.json
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
             name: my-vol-config
```

Error:

```
kubectl apply -f calico-namespace/management-ui.yaml
service "management-ui" unchanged
error: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 20: did not find expected key
```

Comment: I think the lastest yaml is not valid. Check with http://www.yamllint.com for example. I think you will need to remove the dashes before the keys and it will do

Comment: @Tomás Gonzalez Dowling  still the same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This part, `-` should be with `name:` on first line under `volumeMounts`

```
    volumeMounts:
      name: config-volume
    - mountPath: /star/probes.json
```

Like so:

```
    volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /star/probes.json
```

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to add more points that i have learned today,

Mounting a file using the below code will delete any files under the directory in this case star directory in the container.

```
-    volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /star/probes.json
```

to solve it we should use subpath

```
  volumeMounts:
    - name: "config-volume"
      mountPath: "/star/probes.json"
      subPath: "probes.json"
```

Instead of fiddling on how to pass key-value pairs into the data , try passing as json file and remember to specify the namespace while creating the configmap

In my example: I have probes.json and i tried to pass it as such without passing each value to my data. I used the below command to create my configmap

```
kubectl create configmap config --namespace stars --from-file calico-namespace/probes.json
```